# RTSP streaming on VLC

Tags: vlc, rtsp, rtsp-client

We have implemented RTSP server on our MCU. For testing purpose we are using VLC media player as a client.  We coded our MCU such a way that only after receiving PLAY command from client, MCU reads data from camera. And we are seeing MCU receives data from camera and streams thorugh RTSP.  We could see  data streaming from server through UDP on Wireshark. And Also Codec information getting dispalyed on VLC media player. But video doesn't get played in VLC.What could be the issue?
Below is our SDP file info

"v=0\r\ns=Unnamed\r\ni=N/A\r\nc=IN IP4 sumukha-PC\r\nt=0 0\r\na=tool:vlc 2.2.2\r\na=recvonly\r\na=type:broadcast\r\na=charset:UTF-8\r\na=control:rtsp://192.168.1.100:8555\r\nm=video 0 RTP/AVP 96\r\nb=RR:0\r\na=rtpmap:96 H264/90000\r\na=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1\r\na=control:rtsp://192.168.1.100:8555/trackID=0\r\n\r\n");

Thanks,
Ck

Comment: You should spend some effort formatting your question correctly. No one wants to read an SDP where you didn't make the effort to at least put in new lines.

Answer (score 3):

The error message tells you what is going wrong:

> live555 error: no data received in 10s, aborting

The usual reasons for this are firewalls or NAT? 
You can select the RTP over RTSP (TCP) option in the VLC preferences to verify this.  If the stream works over TCP, UDP packets are being blocked somewhere.

Comment: I agree with @Ralf, the RTP over RTSP (TCP) is a NAT Traversal option for VLC. Another NAT-Traversal alternative available is the HTTP streaming type.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using ffmpeg and ffplay to test your streaming from a RTSP source.

It is command line, but the information and logs are very helpful